# Casting to the class with the same base:

Tags: c++, casting

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{ void foo(){ std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; } };

struct D{ void bar(){ std::cout << "bar()" << std::endl; } };

struct B : A, D{ };

struct C : A{ };

B *b = new B();

C *c = reinterpret_cast<C*>(b);

int main(){ c -> foo(); } //prints foo
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa8a0165391e2fa0)**

It works but I'm not sure whether I got some kind of `UB` here. Maybe someone could get a reference to the Standard?

I provided that case because I have two classes (`B`, `C`) and in some module I need to use only a part of `B`'s functionality (`C`'s functionality). But I have already instantiated class `B`, could I just make the `reinterpret_cast` as I did?

Comment: Why not just implicitly cast `B*` to `A*`?

Comment: @Fireho Actually I have more complicated example. I provided that example only to make sure if it could ever be done...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the purpose of reinterpret_cast.

Most docs online has a disclaimer similar to

> Misuse of the reinterpret_cast operator can easily be unsafe. Unless
>   the desired conversion is inherently low-level, you should use one of
>   the other cast operators.
>
> The reinterpret_cast operator can be used for conversions such as
>   char* to int*, **or One_class* to Unrelated_class*, which are inherently**
>   **unsafe**.

This excerpt is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b.aspx). Emphasis mine.

Comment: So, it's not even possible to perform such convertions without UB, is it?

Comment: No, not in the manner stated.  B and C are unrelated.  You could do an actual conversion though.

Comment: You mean explicit convertion, do you?

Comment: Indeed. Conversion function `C* convert(B* original);`